# Elbow method not giving a proper curve

Tags: r, clustering, k-means

I am trying to determine how many clusters to use for my k-means clustering using different methods. Gap statistic is giving me k=4 and Silhouette k=3. I have run k-means with both values and both of them seem to give decent result, but I still do not know which of them are the best. So I used the elbow method as well, in hope of it giving me either 3 or 4 but the plot looks strange and I cannot determine what k should be according to the plot. The total within sum of squares decrease by k=4, but suddenly on k=5 it increases and decreases once again on k=6, creating a "peak" between k=4 and k=6.
[image: Elbow method plot]

I am using the function "fviz_nbclust()" from the package "factoextra" in R:

```
fviz_nbclust(dataset, kmeans, method = "wss")
fviz_nbclust(dataset, kmeans, method = "silhouette")
fviz_nbclust(dataset, kmeans, method = "gap_stat")
```

Any advice would be helpful, as I am fairly new to the subject of clustering and may have missed important or basic knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For kmeans, the default is using nstart=1 , meaning it tries one configuration of centers, and depending on your data, it might give not give a within ss that is smaller than the lower k. Also, it will not give you the same clusters within runs.

For example:

```
set.seed(675)
M = matrix(rnbinom(1000,mu=10,size=1),ncol=10)
fviz_nbclust(M,kmeans,method="wss")
```

[image]

We increase the number of nstart and this should go away:

```
fviz_nbclust(M,kmeans,nstart=10,method="wss")
```

[image]

And I think it might make sense for you to set nstart for the other test.

Comment: I understand now, thank you! I have another question, should one normalize/standardise the data before or after determining number of clusters?

Comment: if you using kmeans, it makes sense to scale the data before clustering. kmeans is done on euclidean distance between your observations, so if your variables have different scales, this would push the separation to be based on columns with higher values

Comment: hope this makes sense....

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Thank you!