# Identifying inflexion point in elbow method (cluster analysis)

Tags: clustering, k-means, model-based-clustering, optimal

I am looking for the optimal number of clusters to conduct a cluster analysis and used the following code to determine it:

```r
    fviz_nbclust(all_dive_data_NA, kmeans, method = "wss")

    fviz_nbclust(all_dive_data_NA, kmeans, method = "silhouette")
```

The silhouette method indicates the optimal number is 2 but the shape of the elbow method is different than the typical "arm" so I'm not sure on how to interpret.

Is the first inflexion point the optimal cluster number (so 2 again) or is it 4?

[image]

Comment: When you do kmeans, you might need to increase the number of starts to get a stable solution. check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/460839/elbow-method-not-giving-a-proper-curve/460884#460884. Try that, if it doesn't work, update your question with the information needed to reproduce the plot above

Comment: This looks not ok, i would run it again several times with other random initalizations and see if the high cost in k=3 stays the same, i guess not :)